# How to create a separate storefront JS file which is working with the Shopware 6 storefront plugins

Tags: javascript, webpack, shopware

I need to create a big JS application in the account area of the Shopware 6 storefront. Since it will be only needed in the account area and the JS total size will be 800kb I don't want to implement it as a regular storefront JS plugin for performance reasons.

Is it somehow possible with a custom webpack.config.js under custom/static-plugins/MyPlugin/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/build to get a seperate JS file which is working with the Jquery and Bootstrap JS in the "main.js" file of Shopware 6?

For example I want to call the Modal JS from Bootstrap via "elementVariable.modal('show')" without importing it in my separate entry file.
Or is this not possible at all since a Webpack bundle is so encapsulated that you can't access it from other files or inline JS?

Any help or hints are much appreciated.

Comment: Does this help?  https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: Yes, I think this is the way to go, but unfortunately I don't get it to work in the Shopware context. But I am pretty sure that it's possible with code splitting to archive what I want, I just never got it to work.

Comment: Feel free to update your question with what you've tried